# The emulator process for AVD Nexus_One_API_27 was killed;emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'Qt event loop'.

Tags: android, android-emulator

while launching emulator I am getting error->Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_One_API_27 was killed. I find that in directory /Android/Sdk/system-images/android-27/google_apis/x86; build.prop and system.img and other files are there. I did vi .android/avd/Nexus_One_API_27.avd/config.ini.In that image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-27/google_apis/x86/. So, I checked the files there.

I have did export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT='/root/Android/Sdk' in command prompt.
But I get the same error

other errors I get is->6:46 PM  Emulator: WARNING: Unknown AVD name

```
[Nexus_One_API_27], use -list-avds to see valid list.

6:46 PM Emulator: HOME is defined but there is no file Nexus_One_API_27.ini in $HOME/.android/avd

6:46 PM Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

6:46 PM Emulator: WARNING: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_One_API_27], use -list-avds to see valid list.

6:46 PM Emulator: HOME is defined but there is no file Nexus_One_API_27.ini in $HOME/.android/avd

6:46 PM Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

6:46 PM Emulator: WARNING: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_One_API_27], use -list-avds to see valid list.

6:46 PM Emulator: HOME is defined but there is no file Nexus_One_API_27.ini in $HOME/.android/avd

6:46 PM Emulator: (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

6:46 PM Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

6:46 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

what should I do to make emulator run?

I have 2android studio installed-one in home and one in root. /the one in home/sandip is not working.
when I do echo $HOME, it shows /home/Sandip in one terminal and /root in other terminal where I have used sudo. I am currently running the studio installed in root;
/root/.android/avd has Nexus_One_API_27.ini file

I fixed the other installation and these are the errors I get while launching emulator

```
5:40 PM Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so

5:40 PM Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

5:40 PM Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

5:41 PM Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

5:41 PM Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

5:41 PM Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

5:41 PM Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)

5:41 PM Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)

5:41 PM Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0

5:41 PM Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  56

5:41 PM Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  57

5:41 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: /home/sandip/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/userdata.img

5:41 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried the following. Now emulator launches but hangs
Itworked for installation in /home/Sandip/ and not for /root/

first have to install the following packages if there not on the system lib64stdc++6 and mesa-utils

sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6 mesa-utils

Then symlink the libraries to the android sdk tools path

1. ### For the /Sdk/tools path

   ```
   cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
   if thisdirectory is not there create it.
   # making a copy of the file
   sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.og
   # symlink
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++

   ## For the /Sdk/emulator path

   cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
   # making a copy of the file
   sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.og 
   # symlink
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
   ```

Then emulator launched but not the app.

Go to sdk manager and select API Level 15 which is Android 4.0.3 (IcecreamSandwich) under SDK Platforms

but this caused my emulator GUI to hang
error is
android Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'Qt event loop'. No response for 15150 ms

Comment: Is this also on the primary monitor? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15648